# Save for web in Illustrator script

Tags: javascript, scripting, photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I made an Illustrator script to batch resize and center JPG pictures. I would like to export the files by sticking it to artboard while keeping a 96 DPI.

The classical export as JPG recorded script works, but the size of the picture is based on DPI while it should be the same dimension as the artboard.

I recorded another script with Export for web action, but I need to confirm the export for each picture while I have DONTDISPLAYALERTS.

Now I found a direct way to add this action to the script, but apparently it only works with Photoshop:

```js
function main(){  
if(!documents.length) return;  
var Name = app.activeDocument.name.replace(/\.[^\.]+$/, '');   
var saveFile = File(Folder.desktop + "/" + Name + ".jpg");  
if(saveFile.exists){  
   if(!confirm("Overwrite existing document?")) return;  
    saveFile.remove();  
    }  
SaveForWeb(saveFile,100); //change to 60 for 60%  
}  
main();  
function SaveForWeb(saveFile,jpegQuality) {  
var sfwOptions = new ExportOptionsSaveForWeb();   
   sfwOptions.format = SaveDocumentType.JPEG;   
   sfwOptions.includeProfile = false;   
   sfwOptions.interlaced = 0;   
   sfwOptions.optimized = true;   
   sfwOptions.quality = jpegQuality; //0-100   
activeDocument.exportDocument(saveFile, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, sfwOptions);  
}
```

Would you know which Illustrator function can replace ExportOptionsSaveForWeb() ?

Thank you !